# how to unite all files from several subfolders into one big folder?

Tags: filesystem

how can I copy all files, with different extensions, from several different subdirectories, into one main folder?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not wanting to keep the directory structure and just want to move all the files into one folder, you can do something like this.

```
find /src/folder/1 /src/folder/2 -type f -exec cp {} /path/to/destination/ \;
```

This will find every file `-type f` from the given source folders, then execute the `-exec` command on them.  In this case, you want to copy `cp` them into the destination folder.

Keep in mind, this will fully traverse the source folders recursively.  If you want to only go deep a certain level into the source directories, use the `-maxdepth` options on the find command.

```
find /src/folder/1 /src/folder/2 -type f -maxdepth 2 -exec cp {} /path/to/destination/ \;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
find ./ -type f -exec cp '{}' ./ \;
```